# can any one help me to solve this python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a python program that will take a String as input from the user. It will print “Found”, if 4 consecutive lowercase letters are found, otherwise “Not Found”.

[You cannot use any built in function except input(), print(), len(String), ord(String), chr(int).]
Sample input 1: aFrese111
Sample output 1: Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following script, it has been taken into account that the "ord" built-in function returns a value between 97(a) and 122(z) for lower-case letters:

```
def foundOrNot (string):
    consecutiveLower = 0
    
    for i in  (string):
        unicodeNumber = ord(i)
        
        if consecutiveLower == 4:
            break
            
        elif (unicodeNumber >= 97 and unicodeNumber <= 122):
            consecutiveLower += 1
            
        else:
            consecutiveLower = 0
        
    if (consecutiveLower == 4):
        print ("Found")
    else:
        print ("Not found")

testString = input()

foundOrNot(testString)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This would not work with the restrictions added to the question

This script should do the trick.

```
import re
def program():
  input_text = input("Write a string")
  found = re.findall("[a-z]{4}", input_text)
  if(len(found) > 0):
    print("found")
  else:
    print("not found")
```

The script imports re which is a *regular expression*(regex) library. The method *input* lets the user type in the terminal and stores whatever the user typed in the **input_text** variable. Then we use the regex method *findall* with the query [a-z]{4}. This is a way to check if 4 and only 4 characters in succession are lowercased. Then we store our (possibly) found sections in the **found** variable. After this is done, we check for the length of the found variable (which is a list of possible sections). If the list is bigger than zero we found an instance, if not, we print "not found".